# Log 'String or binary data would be truncated' SQL Server side

Tags: sql-server, logging, report

I have one SQL Server instance accessed by many different applications.
Sometimes happened that one of such application throw the exception : "String or binary data would be truncated".

My objective is to trace (logging) when that error happen, and trace down which application has encountered the problem on which field.
I have no access to every application's code, so my first idea is to develop a solution directly in the SQL Server, but i don't know how can i check if that problem is occured and on which field.

Comment: Use Extended Events to track and trace such errors. This particular error is 8152. https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/grahamk/2010/12/10/extended-event-to-track-and-trace-syntax-errors/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> but i don't know how can i check if that problem is occured and on which field.

even SQL server won't tell you on which field it occurred.There is a connect item ,which has been logged for the same

https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/339410/please-fix-the-string-or-binary-data-would-be-truncated-message-to-give-the-column-name

But you  can catch those errors,with a simple try catch and log them

```
create table #t1
(
charcol char(1)

)


begin try
insert into #t1
values
    ('a'),
    ('aa')
end try

begin catch
select error_message()
end catch
```

This is fixed in Recent versions of SQLServer..Now you will be able to know the exact column

> Msg 2628, Level 16, State 1, Line 9
> String or binary data would be truncated in
> table 'StackOverflow2013.dbo.CoolPeople', column 'PrimaryCar'.
> Truncated value: '2006 Subaru Impreza '.

This works in SQL Server 2019 if you enable database scoped settings like below

> ALTER DATABASE SCOPED CONFIGURATION
> SET VERBOSE_TRUNCATION_WARNINGS = ON;

you have to turn traceflag 460 for SQL Server 2016-2017

**References and Examples:**
https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2019/03/how-to-fix-the-error-string-or-binary-data-would-be-truncated/

Comment: I have no control over those operations, third party software operate over this SQL Server instance, i only have to monitor this instance.
I suppose some of those software use LinqToSql or EF to connect with DB and i can see their activiteis (in the activity monitor) but i don't know how to isolate only the actvities that throw this error